# Is $W(0,T;H^1, L^2) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(M))$ dense in $W(0,T;H^1, H^{-1})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold that is closed. Define
$$W(0,T, H^1, L^2) = \{ u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(M)) \mid u_t \in L^2(0,T;L^2(M))\}$$
$$W(0,T, H^1, H^{-1}) = \{ u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(M)) \mid u_t \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(M))\}$$
Is $W(0,T;H^1, L^2) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(M))$ dense in $W(0,T;H^1, H^{-1})$?

There must be some result like $C^\infty([0,T]\times M)$ is dense in $W(0,T;H^1, H^{-1})$ but I can't seem to find a reference..

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some additional details. What do you mean by $X(M)$? I am assuming $H^1$ is a Sobolev space and $H^{-1}$ is its dual, but what is the underlying space? Are we dealing with $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ or $H^1(\Omega)$ for bounded $\Omega$, for instance?

Comment: @Jason I edited. Yes I mean the usual Sobolev spaces, and $M$ is a closed Riemannian manifold.